# How to print the score related to each line separately?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a data printed in line (strings) and the scores of each line. I need to combine each line with its specific score. for example the data is as follows :

```
[2.0,-2.0,-2.0,-2.0,2.0,-2.0,2.0,-2.0,2.0,-2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0] 
[-2.0,-2.0,0.0,-2.0,-2.0,-2.0,-2.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,-2.0,0.0]
[2.0,0.0,-2.0,2.0,2.0,-2.0,0.0,0.0,-2.0,0.0,-2.0,0.0,-2.0,0.0]
[2.0,2.0,-2.0,-2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,-2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,-2.0,2.0]
[-2.0,0.0,-2.0,-2.0,0.0,0.0,-2.0,2.0,-2.0,-2.0,2.0,2.0,0.0,0,0]
```

while the scores as follows

```
0.003484028626591704
0.023784473319415262
0.09279109045534298
0.14760754728366166
0.16830002995397936
```

so the result should be each line must take the related score as follows

```
[2.0,-2.0,-2.0,-2.0,2.0,-2.0,2.0,-2.0,2.0,-2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0] 0.003484028626591704
[-2.0,-2.0,0.0,-2.0,-2.0,-2.0,-2.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,-2.0,0.0] 0.023784473319415262
[2.0,0.0,-2.0,2.0,2.0,-2.0,0.0,0.0,-2.0,0.0,-2.0,0.0,-2.0,0.0] 0.09279109045534298
[2.0,2.0,-2.0,-2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,-2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,-2.0,2.0] 0.14760754728366166
[-2.0,0.0,-2.0,-2.0,0.0,0.0,-2.0,2.0,-2.0,-2.0,2.0,2.0,0.0,0,0] 0.16830002995397936
```

so far i use the following code

```
 double []  fX3 =new double [numberofrows];
    double d=0.0;
    for(int r = 0; r < numberoffeatures-1; r++) 
        {
            List<Double> array1=  new ArrayList<Double>();


            for(int c = 0; c < numberofrows; c++)
            {
                int valf3 = datasetMat[c][r];
                fX3[c] = valf3;
                array1.add(fX3[c]);
                     for (int i = 0; i<su.noAttributes(); i++){
                  d = (su.score(i));}
                } 
           System.out.println(array1+" "+d);
 }
```

but it gives me the following result where all the lines take the last score which is not right

```
[2.0,-2.0,-2.0,-2.0,2.0,-2.0,2.0,-2.0,2.0,-2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0] 0.16830002995397936
[-2.0,-2.0,0.0,-2.0,-2.0,-2.0,-2.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,-2.0,0.0] 0.16830002995397936
[2.0,0.0,-2.0,2.0,2.0,-2.0,0.0,0.0,-2.0,0.0,-2.0,0.0,-2.0,0.0] 0.16830002995397936
[2.0,2.0,-2.0,-2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,-2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,-2.0,2.0] 0.16830002995397936
[-2.0,0.0,-2.0,-2.0,0.0,0.0,-2.0,2.0,-2.0,-2.0,2.0,2.0,0.0,0,0] 0.16830002995397936
```

An help would be appreciated

Comment: It's probably better if you ask your question in a more generic context. From what I'm understanding you want to loop over a 2d array and calculate some kind of total from each value in each row?

Comment: the column counts of each row do not equal with each other?

Comment: @martijnp.. Tq for yr reply.. I have edited the question . it is just how to combine each line with its score rather than taking all the lines the same score

Comment: sorry @caisil, I edited the example because my data file is quite huge and I take just example from it

Comment: no understand the demo code. What's the structure of  `du`?  Perhaps try to put `d = (su.score(r));` out the second loop.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i<su.noAttributes(); i++){d = (su.score(i));}` never change for each iteration.

Comment: Thanks @caisil for yr answer d = (su.score(r)); It was working

Comment: @caisil, please post your comment as an answer so that the user11801243 can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove

```
for (int i = 0; i<su.noAttributes(); i++){
                  d = (su.score(i));}
```

and change `System.out.println(array1+" "+d);` to `System.out.println(array1+" "+su.score(r));`